# Are atomic transactions supposed to produce more connection.queries in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following in my models:

```
from django.db import models

class X(models.Model):
    ...

class Y(models.Model):
    ...
    x = models.ForeignKey(X, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Z(models.Model):
    ...
    y = models.ForeignKey(Y, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In one of my views, I am updating all my models like so:

```
from .models import X, Y, Z
from django.db import connection, transaction


def do_something(bro, z_pk):
    z = Z.objects.select_related('y__x').get(pk=z_pk)
    y = z.y
    x = y.x

    ...

    with transaction.atomic():
        z.save()
        y.save()
        x.save()

    print(len(connection.queries))
```

With the `transaction.atomic()`, the length of queries is 5. However, without it, the length returned is 4. That is, the following code:

```
from .models import X, Y, Z
from django.db import connection


def do_something(bro, z_pk):
    z = Z.objects.select_related('y__x').get(pk=z_pk)
    y = z.y
    x = y.x

    ...

    z.save()
    y.save()
    x.save()

    print(len(connection.queries))
```

Returns a length of 4. Is this normal or am I missing something? Moreover, with the `transaction.atomic()`, am I hitting my database less times? Its difficult to understand that based on the `connection.queries`.

Note: The extra query in the atomic function is the following:

```
{'sql': 'BEGIN', 'time': '0.000'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`BEGIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-begin.html) statement is simply PostgreSQL's way of starting a transaction. So that's why you see it in the example with the transaction. (There should also be a `COMMIT` statement, but perhaps Django doesn't count it.)

Without an explicit transaction Django and the database operate in [autocommit mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#autocommit), so there's no need for the additional statement.

Note that the number of queries is different from how many times you "hit the database", since more than one query can be sent at the same time. (I'm not sure if Django has a way to report how many round-trips have been made to the database.) In any case, I think it's safe to say that there is no need to worry about a performance hit from executing a `BEGIN` statement. (Though using transactions in general can have an impact on the overall performance of the application.)